# Mapbox Directions API route, get information from markers

Tags: mapbox-gl, turfjs, mapbox-marker

I'm extremely new to Mapbox so please forgive me if this has been answered before.

I'm building a navigation web app using the following link:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/route-finder-with-turf-mapbox-directions/

Is it possible to retrieve the marker details (street address and name) if a navigation route passes the marker?

Comment: Try [`queryRenderedFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures)

Comment: @Taku I'm quite new to Mapbox. Is there a user friendly user guide you can recommend?

Comment: You can take a look at some resources. ([link1](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/feature-querying/), [link2](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/feature-querying/))